# BounceCategoryID from Bounce Dataview field doesn't return the right value to Boolean field

Tags: query, sql, automationstudio, data-views, bounce-management

I have problems during SQL that it doesn't retrieve the right value to Boolean field.

Now I extract Bounce DataView and if BounceCategoryID(number type) is 1002,1003 then retrieve 'true' to Spam field(boolean type) and else are 'false'.

I write a query like belows, but it only retrieve 'False' in Spam field.
Is there any points that i missed?

```
SELECT
    AccountID, 
    OYBAccountID, 
    JobID, 
    ListID, 
    BatchID, 
    SubscriberID, 
    SubscriberKey, 
    EventDate, 
    Domain, 
    BounceCategoryID, 
    BounceCategory, 
    BounceSubcategoryID, 
    BounceSubcategory, 
    BounceTypeID, 
    BounceType, 
    SMTPBounceReason, 
    SMTPMessage, 
    SMTPCode, 
    TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID, 
    TriggeredSendCustomerKey,
    CASE
        WHEN BounceCategoryID IN ('1001', '1002') THEN 'True'
        ELSE 'False'
    END AS Spam
FROM 
    _Bounce
```

Also, I've been change query for 3 kinds.

```
 CASE
            WHEN BounceCategoryID IN (1001, 1002) THEN 'True'
            ELSE 'False'
        END AS Spam
   

     CASE
            WHEN CAST(BounceCategoryID AS VARCHAR(10)) IN ('1001', '1002') THEN 'True'
            ELSE 'False'
        END AS Spam

CASE
    WHEN BounceCategoryID = 1002 OR BounceCategoryID = 1003 THEN 'True'
    ELSE 'False'
END AS Spam
```

All of these queries doesn't retrieve right value to Spam field.
If there are any points that I missed?

Thanks for your corporation!